# Why is this proof wrong of complex function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to [prove Theorem 2.7 in Duren's multivalent functions book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0k0F.png). In the theorem, we have

$$
F(z)=\frac{f\left(\frac{z+\zeta}{1+\bar{\zeta}z}\right)-f(\zeta)}{(1-|\zeta|^2)f^\prime(\zeta)},
$$
$$
F(z)=\frac{z}{(1+e^{i\theta}z)^2},\,\,\,\,\,\,e^{i\theta}=\bar{\zeta}/|\zeta|,
$$
$$
G(w)=F\left(\frac{w-\zeta}{1-\bar{\zeta}w}\right)
$$
with $w=\frac{z+\zeta}{1+\bar{\zeta}z}$ or $z=\frac{w-\zeta}{1-\bar{\zeta}w}$.
From these equations it is stated without proof that $f(w)$ is a constant multiple of
$$
G(w)-G(0)=\frac{(1+|\zeta|)^2}{1-|\zeta|}\frac{w}{(1+e^{-i\theta} w)^2}
$$

However, in my proof I got that $G(w)-G(0)=\frac{(1+|\zeta|)^2}{(1-|\zeta|)^2}\frac{w}{(1+e^{-i\phi} w)^2}$. Why this wrong?

My proof:

$$
G(w)-G(0)=\frac{(\frac{(w-\zeta)}{(1-w\bar{\zeta})})}{(1+\frac{(w-\zeta)}{(1-w\bar{\zeta})}  e^{iθ} )^2} -\frac{-\zeta}{(1-\zeta e^{iθ} )^2}
=\frac{(\zeta^2 w-\zeta^3-w^2 \zeta|\zeta|^2+w α^2 |\zeta|^2)}{(\zeta-w|\zeta|^2+w|\zeta|-\zeta|\zeta|)^2 }+\frac{\zeta}{(1-\zeta e^{iθ} )^2}
=\frac{(\zeta^2 w+w \zeta^2 |\zeta|^2+2\zeta^2 |\zeta|w)}{((1-|\zeta|)^2 (\zeta+|\zeta|w)^2 )}
=\frac{(1+|\zeta|)^2}{(1-|\zeta|)^2}   \frac{w}{(1+e^{-iθ} w)^2 }
$$

Comment: most likely it is a typo and $G(w)-G(0)$ is what you claim but there is no contradiction as the book just claims that $f(w)$ is a constant multiple of $\frac{w}{(1+e^{-i\phi} w)^2}$ as both $\frac{(1+|\zeta|)^2}{(1-|\zeta|)^2}, \frac{(1+|\zeta|)^2}{(1-|\zeta|)}$ are such constants in terms of $w$ so the result holds with either as coefficients of $G(w)-G(0)$

Comment: @Conrad, but this is a standard textbook used in many classes. Maybe my calculation is wrong.

Comment: The typo is irrelevant as noted and I think your calculation is correct (looks right if you look at degrees in $\zeta$) so I wouldn't worry about it